# How to hide/unhide one of two lines in a same plot?

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop

I have a plot with two lines. The data ranges are very different in both lines. It I put them into a single plot without any further formatting, then one of these lines will look like a streight lines in the bottom of a plot. This happens because this line is composed of values 101, 99, 102, ..., while the second line is composed of values 10002, 12000, etc.

[image]

Is it possible to place both of these lines in a sinlge line plot? I wanted to use a dual Y axis. Or maybe there is an option of hiding/unhiding lines (with automatic rescaling).

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sadly, the line chart does not support dual axis at this time.  Another out-of-the-box visual, the bar-line combo, can. Otherwise, there are a few work-arounds you can employ.

So, this depends a bit on your data model.  When your two lines are each a series (a column) of their own, then there is no way to make a line hide or 'disappear.'  However, if the lines are generated as a result of being split by a legend, then you can definitely filter one of them away, just by making the 'type' field used in the legend as a slicer.

[image]

But if you've got your data in distinct series (maybe they're from different tables or dissimilar things that don't belong in the same column), you can cheat a bit by creating a new measure and applying your scale transform there.  So, if your 1st line was gadgets and your second line was widgets, and you created a new measure or column 'hundreds of widgets' = widgets / 100, then these two would graph nearby on the same chart.  It's pretty much the same thing, if you think about it.

[image]

So, there's some food for thought.  Good luck!